# Indentation in REPLs

Tags: indentation, repl

I can't seem to get indentation working properly in the REPLs I've used so far (IELM, MIT-Scheme, and Python).

Suppose I type the following and RET:

```
ELISP> (defun something ()
_
```

My cursor ends up at the underscore, and pressing TAB doesn't seem to do anything. The same thing happens with the MIT-Scheme REPL.

To be explicit, I'd like to have it automatically indent it like so:

```
ELISP> (defun something ()
         _
```

In IELM, TAB is bound to `ielm-tab` which is supposed to "Indent or complete". The function calls `ielm-indent-line` at the beginning of a line. Calling `ielm-indent-line` directly does not indent the line as advertised.

In the Python REPL, it does indent just enough to get past the prompt, but not more. For example:

```
>>> def something():
... _
```

I was hoping to be able to have the Python REPL automatically indent like in regular Python files. The mode description doesn't seem to turn up any relevant results for 'indent'.

`electric-indent-mode` is enabled in all cases. Would anybody know what I'm missing?

**Edit:** I noticed that `ielm-indent-line` is supposed to (but evidently does not) call `lisp-indent-line`. Calling `lisp-indent-line` directly *does* work in IELM, but not Inferior Scheme/MIT-Scheme.
Calling `python-indent-line` in the Python REPL also does not work.

Comment: FWIW, I have run into this issue as well, which, at first glance, looks like an Emacs24-specific bug, as IELM indentation works OOTB in both 23 and 25.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of changes in `ielm` and `comint` from Emacs 23 to 24 introduced what looks like a bug in determining the position of the start of a `comint`-derived line, which in turn affects whether indentation is attempted in `ielm`. This bug seems to have been fixed in Emacs 25.

Compare the definition of `ielm-indent-line` in Emacs 23 and 24:

```el
(defun ielm-indent-line nil
  "Indent the current line as Lisp code if it is not a prompt line."
  (when (save-excursion (comint-bol) (bolp))
    (lisp-indent-line)))
```

with that in Emacs 25:

```el
(defun ielm-indent-line nil
  "Indent the current line as Lisp code if it is not a prompt line."
  (when (save-excursion (comint-bol t) (bolp))
    (lisp-indent-line)))
```

I haven't investigated what happens in other REPLs, but anything derived from `comint` could conceivably suffer from a similar issue. Evaluating the Emacs 25 definition of `ielm-indent-line` in Emacs 24 resolved the indentation issues I was seeing in `ielm`.